# conflict in declaring classes and inheritance

Tags: c++

I have a class `Point` and `Vector`
  `Vector` inherits from  `Point` and `Point` uses `Vector` as friend
  I have one cpp file..how do I resolve this conflict.
  I dont want to use header files
  My Code is :

```
 class Vector:Point
 {
  //something
 };

 class Point
 {
 public:
     friend class Vector;

     double x;
     double y;
     Vector Point::operator-( Point Q)        // Vector diff of Points
     {
         Vector v;
         v.x = x - Q.x;
         v.y = y - Q.y;
         v.z = z - Q.z;
         v.dimn = max( dimn, Q.dim());
         return v;
     }

     Point Point::operator+( Vector v)        // +ve translation
     {
         Point P;
         P.x = x + v.x;
         P.y = y + v.y;
         P.z = z + v.z;
         P.dimn = max( dimn, v.dim());
         return P;
     }

     Point Point::operator-( Vector v)        // -ve translation
     {
         Point P;
         P.x = x - v.x;
         P.y = y - v.y;
         P.z = z - v.z;
         P.dimn = max( dimn, v.dim());
         return P;
     }

     Point& Point::operator+=( Vector v)        // +ve translation
     {
         x += v.x;
         y += v.y;
         z += v.z;
         dimn = max( dimn, v.dim());
         return *this;
     }

     Point& Point::operator-=( Vector v)        // -ve translation
     {
         x -= v.x;
         y -= v.y;
         z -= v.z;
         dimn = max( dimn, v.dim());
         return *this;
     }
};
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use header files? How are you expecting the rest of the code to interact with these classes?

Comment: when i fwd declare i get forward declaration of ‘struct Point’

Comment: Why does `Vector` inherit from `Point` (and why is it missing an access specifier)?  Why is `Point` a `friend class` if it's a child?

Comment: I am trying ot use a code at http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0301/algorithm_0301.htm#point.h take a look u might get a feel of wgat i am tryng to do

Answer (score 1):

try forward declarations -

```
class Vector;
class Point { ... }
```

Comment: @AalokParikh: oddly enough, this answer contains the same information as the other answers. feel free to delete it if offended by conciseness ;)

Answer (score 1):

try forward declaring the Point class like so:

```
class Point;

class Vector : Point
{ /* your code here */ };

class Point
{ /* your code here */ };
```

Comment: forward declaration of ‘struct Point’

Comment: @abbas As a guess, you probably should rearrange the classes to declare Point first and move the implementation of the functions outside the body and beneath both classes.  If that doesn't help, you'll have to post some of the code from Vector to get more of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

add the "forward declaration" before the first use of point with:

```
class Point;
```

That's all.  It says there exists a class Point which will be declared later.